# Generate table relationship diagram from existing Oracle schema

Tags: oracle, database-schema, table-relationships

My company has an existing Database with dozens of DB tables with various relationships.

Is there any tool available that will generate a relationship diagram?

I primarily use SQL Developer 3.0.4 on an Ubuntu 11.10 machine by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Developer Data Modeller](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) can reverse engineer a database schema & make a start on an  ERD using the foreign keys. Obviously some manual work will be needed once the initial import has been done in order to generate a nice looking meaningful diagram.

Since you already have SQL Developer installed, you can make a start with `File->Data Modeller->Import->Data Dictionary`.